# Chrome Input text width

Tags: css, google-chrome, text, input, width

I'm having a problem with Chrome, I made a input with 250px width but in the browser Chrome the width is always different from the others browsers for example in the firefox works great and in IE7 too.

I also have a css reset, is this one: http://pastebin.com/jQVxwQqq

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
    width: 210px;
    height: 28px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px 1px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px 1px #000;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222, #333);

    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

<input type="text" class="username">
```

Chrome and Firefox:
http://oi43.tinypic.com/fo0vq.jpg

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I think I have found the problem if I remove this php code from the top of my page It will work

```
<?php
    include "core/functions.php";

    if(logged())
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
```

core/functions.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function logged() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
?>
```

Still I don't know why and how to fix it...

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, I have found how to fix it, this is what I did:

I had this:

```
<?php
    include("core/functions.php");

    if(logged())
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

And I changed to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
    include("core/functions.php");

    if(logged())
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
```

It seems to be working, I'm not sure why, if someone could explain to me I appreciate it. Thanks for the help anyway ;)

Comment: It has the same width in firefox and chrome http://jsfiddle.net/VF55u/1/ . I have included all of your CSS.

Comment: Same for me also.  You might have some additional CSS interfering with the final result.  Also, the width of this is `222px` over all, `1px + 5px + 210px + 5px + 1px`.

Comment: That's odd, because in jsfiddle its working but in my computer its not working...

Comment: Lke @hungerstar was saying, it's probably some other css definition intruding on the input. Use your browser tools to inspect the element and see where the extra width is coming from.

Comment: `user agent stylesheet` of Chrome added its own style like `margin, padding, border` etc... you have to overwrite `user agent stylesheet` css then only it will show proper on chrome